# How to load CMU pocketsphinx in MS Visual Studio 2013? (C++)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, speech-recognition

I am trying to get Pocketsphinx working with visual studio 2013(Ultimate) but after 2 days of searching for how to do it, I have lost hope. Can you tell me how to get it working? I have downloaded the CMU sphinxbase also but I don't know how to set it up. The webpage just says to compile the sphinxbase.sln and then pocketsphinx.sln but that doesn't work. When i tried compiling the sphinxbase.sln i was getting a missing .../bin/debug/sphinxbase.dll

Any help or a step to step guide will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: i just downloaded the win32 precompiled library for CMU Sphinxbase but i still don't know how to set it up. Please help!

Comment: Can you tell us what Pocketsphinx is? What kind of files do you have? Is it supposed to create a library or a DLL?

Comment: Its a speech recognition library. http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx
I am not able to integrate it with MSVC 2013.

Comment: You need to be more precise and describe exactly what problems do you meet, then it would be easy to solve them.

You probably miss sphinxbase.dll when you compile pocketsphinx, not sphinxbase

Sphinxbase.dll and pocketsphinx.dll are added to the hello world project just as any DLL library. You can find documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx